# How can we create loading window in dark background effect

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs

We would like to place, dark background effect ( normally we are using for Images gallery. ) for Loading a page. Actually we have a HTML form, with textarea box and a submit button only. We would simply getting the data from PHP through ajax. here we would like to implement Loading image with dark background effects. When a whole data will print on the screen then , the loading image with dark background back to the normal background.

Thanks

Rodger

Update :- Using this code for getting value from php file. I m beginner in Ajax/ JS, if anybody can give me the code structure, that's good for us.

```
var anchorUrl2 = 'script.php';
var anchorPars1 = 'sqt=abcsd';
var anchorAjax2 = new Ajax.Updater( 'div-id', anchorUrl2, { method: 'get', parameters: anchorPars1 });
```

Comment: Nice idea. What's the problem?

Comment: look at this http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/ , that suits my requirement. but i unable to implement it on our programe.

Answer (score 2):

- On form submit [append](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) a div to `body` tag
- Set this div's position to fixed, width and height to window's width and height
- Assign a semi-transparent black PNG as it's background
- Write a text inside saying 'Please wait'
- Use a callback function when ajax request done to [remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) this div

Comment: +1 for answer that doesn't require including enormous jQuery library

Answer (score 1):

Try this, the code should be self explanatory. It's jquery code but you can take the idea out of it.

```
<script type="text/javascript>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#contentToHideWhileLoading").hide();
    $("#contentToShowWhileLoading").show();
    $.get(url, {parameters: anchorPars1}, function(data){
        $("#placeToAppendTo").append(data.dataToAppend);
        $("#contentToShowWhileLoading").hide();
        $("#contentToHideWhileLoading").show();
        $("#placeToAppendTo").show(); // if it wasn't visible yet
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: i have not installed lightbox2 at the moment.

Comment: Due to my less knowledge in AJAX/JS. May i know, where we place these codes into the page.

Comment: @fmsf - the question has `prototype` as one of its tags, so its reasonable to assume he's using the prototype library. It would be better to offer a solution that works with that than to tell him to install another whole library.

Comment: @spudley - oops sry, didn't noticed. then my apologies, the main concepts are the same though. I don't have much time to change it right now. I'll let the answer stay here as a reference.

Comment: We have to mention it on any <div> or we have to make it with required name ??